# jQuery: Compactly function window.resize (doesn't repeat)

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$(function someFunction() {
   //here is my function
});

$(window).on('resize', function() {
   //here the same
});
```

Is there a better way to rewrite this more compactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, any number of ways

```
$(function() {
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
       // here is your function
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```

or

```
function doStuff() {
    // here is your function
}

$(doStuff);
$(window).on('resize', doStuff);
```

Comment: I think this answer would be completely perfect if it would just also explain the difference between `$(window).on('resize', doStuff);` and `$(window).on('resize', doStuff());` and how this affects arguments and such things. -- and why you re-trigger the resize event

Comment: @Babydead Why `$(window).on('resize', doStuff());` would be relevant to explain here?

Comment: Your second example could give unexpected behaviour if called before the DOM is ready

Comment: @A.Wolff - you're right, and it's basically the same as the first example anyway

Comment: @A.Wolff because question is about very basic jQuery/js, so the OP might actually need that information, since this knowledge is obviously lacking. When I had a similar question ~5 years ago, I sure as hell wished somebody would've explained that to me. I was stuck on it for hours, stressing out like crazy :D

Comment: @Babydead Ok but it looks out of topic here

Comment: @A.Wolff I'm afraid that in a few hours/days we'll have the same person coming back with a question why something isn't working, and it having that exact detail wrong. It's not entirely off-topic because Adeneo recommended to use such a way to call to a function. I would say it *is* important to know why he calls the function without parenthesis. If I tell you to use a specific way to call something, I will explain the reason behind it. Not just go "It's like this!" Boom, solved. Our answers are supposed to inform, teach and spread knowledge, not do people's work for them.